# How to make Date as first column

Tags: r

I have a list data consisting of 500 Dataframes. Each Dataframe have same dimensions. Now I want to add first column as Date in every dataframe.

I have generated date as values. I have tried it using map and lapply. But it does not solve.

Now I want everydataframe having date as first column.

Comment: ok @RonakShah i will read all this stuff and ask question in proper sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `Map` to `cbind` the `vector` of dates with each element of the `list` ('lst1')

```
Map(cbind, Date = list(DateVec), lst1)
```

---

Or with `lapply`

```
lapply(lst1, function(x) cbind(Date = DateVec, x))
```

Comment: @simar For `Map` wrap with `list`.  Please check the updated post